# how to avoid synchronization issue in writing contents to file - Java ( android)

Tags: java, android, file, queue, synchronize

I have a requirement which updates the file contents from multiple operation which can occur at the same time.

I need to queue each request and the change the contents of the file for each request one by one.

I am using android broadcast receiver which receives the events for changing the file contents.

How can I queue this events and make changes to file one after the other request.

Please provide some suggestion or if possible please provide any links that I can refer.

Comment: Let each request send a code, save this code, implement an observer which checks the code and relays it to a synchronized block for writing. Let the code be priority or the request dispatch number. Alternatively you can also use a broadcast which notifies waiting writers of the status of the current thread holding the synchronized lock over write operation.

Comment: Unclear. First: where are these events written in the file? At the end? Anywhere in the file?

Comment: @fge - need to rewrite entire file for each event

Comment: Uh, I see. What is the frequency of events?

Comment: It can happen 2-5 events in 2 min or it might not happen for 1 hour as well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used executor with single thread. When event is received, we can post runnable to the executor. As the pool has 1 thead, these tasks will run in sequence.

Answer (score 3):

I came, several time ago, across a class used by Android internally to serve the purpose you want to reach and which is now available through the `Android Support Library`.

It's called `AtomicFile`, it is documented [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/util/AtomicFile) and you can find its implementation [here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/util/AtomicFile.java).